# How to grab context data for Related Model with ManyToManyFiled Relation in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models Named Teacher and Class, like below. Where Class and Teacher are related to ManyToManyField in the class_instructor field. That means a class has more than one teacher. Now I wanted to show all the teachers that belong to that particular class instance and in the Class Detail View.

My Teacher Model

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    teachers_name = models.CharField(max_length=32,help_text="Enter a Teachers Name here")
    teachers_speciality = models.CharField(max_length=32,help_text="Enter a Teachers Speciality.e.g. Drawing Instructor")
    teachers_description = models.TextField(max_length=1200,help_text="Enter a Teachers Description")
    teachers_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.teachers_name
```

My Class Model

```
class Class(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=120,help_text="Enter the class Name here")
    class_duration = models.CharField(max_length=30,help_text="Enter class duration",default='1 Year')
    class_instructor = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)
    available_seats = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=30)
    class_description = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    course_description = models.TextField(max_length=2500,blank=True,null=True)
    course_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,help_text="Enter the course type here,e.g. Basic")
    class_iamge = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    class_iamge_detail = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    class_added_at = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    student_ages = models.IntegerField()
    tution_fee = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("class_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

I have tried the following way, like using get_context_data where I tried to filter my Teacher
model with associated pk of the class detail. But unable to figure out anything that works. Instead, I showed all the teachers in the class detail page, but I wanted to show the teachers that only associated the current class in the class details views.

My Class Detail views

```
class ClassDetailView(DetailView): ## this context will bring the Class corrospondint to that pk
    model = Class
    template_name = 'home/class_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'class'



    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        # this context will bring the Class corrospondnt to that pk
        context = super(ClassDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['teachers'] = Teacher.objects.all()
        print(context)
        return context
```

In my templates, I am trying to shows like below.......

```
{% for teacher in teachers %}
<div class="teacher">
    <img src="{% static 'images/team/teacher/1.jpg' %}" alt="teacher">
    <h2>{{teacher.teachers_name}}</h2>
    <span>{{teacher.teachers_speciality}}</span>
    <p>{{teacher.teachers_description}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write teacher filter like following,

```py
class_id = 10 # Your class details id may be
context['teachers'] = Teacher.objects.filter(class_set__id=class_id)
```